# How to prevent the extra tone from the upper part of the guitar

Tags: technique, acoustic-guitar

I have a problem with my technique especially when tapping the higher notes. There is always a tone from the upper part of the fretboard that I don't want, but having a hard time muting it. Any ideas?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: You mean the lower part of the fretboard, closer to the nut/machine heads?

Answer (score 4):

Dampen the strings below the frets you are tapping. Usually by using a finger on the fretting hand that's not doing anything else. Maybe this means re-positioning your fretting fingers, to free up the index.

Answer (score 3):

You may buy or prepare a string dampener (elasic hair or guitar version) [image: string dampener].

Comment: You can also just wrap a scarf around the neck up near the nut - of course I only do that when recording, it would look a lot less cool in a live setting.